# Importing NPM-installed Libraries for Usage in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Inside my component, I have

```
  didInsertElement: function() {

    $('#' + this.idVal).tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 1,
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
```

I am trying to use the `npm` package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-tokenfield`.

However, I noticed that `$().tokenfield()` is undefined meaning that I am not importing it properly. I tried adding it to the `ember-cli-build.js` but I noticed that it is probably importing `bootstrap-tokenfield` before jquery which causes issues. (Is this the case the `ember.build.js` imports those files before any dependencies?)

Am I supposed to import bootstrap-tokenfield in the component somehow if I am trying to use it with npm install?

I am using Ember 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to import npm package to ember client side code you can use ember-browserify (https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify),
inside your project you can simply do

`import MyCoolModule from "npm:my-cool-module";`

Comment: Thanks Bek, I will give it a try. So I noticed that for example jquery is available to the Ember client code. What JavaScript libraries are available by default?

Comment: By default only jquery available, but you can add any clientside libs with bower then you will need import them in ember-cli-build.js file more info here (http://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help. How do I know where the module is getting pulled from? For example, I get the following: `Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/node_modules/jquery-ui'`. In my component, I have `import jQueryUI from "npm:jquery-ui";`. Why is it looking for the module `jquery`?